# Pig lookup external records by a set of keys

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have data in a database system that I can't pull with the LOAD statement for a couple of reasons. I need Pig to lookup this data by key (identifier) but I am concerned about the performance of one-by-one key lookup if I implement a Java UDF. Basically, if my relation has 10,000 entries on it I want to somehow lookup this data in sets of 500 keys. Does Pig provide an interface that would allow me to call a java method that will take in a set of keys and return a set (bag or map) of answers that can be joined or somehow assigned to the Tuple in the Pig relation?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of suggestions:

- Can you write your UDF to expect a bag of identifiers to query in a single batch - then you'll just need to write the pig to divide up your 10,000 identifiers into a number of batches (bags - although i'm not sure how 'easy' this is), and then the subsequent pig code to flatten and rejoin the UDF output
- Use the [MAPREDUCE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#mapreduce) keyword, and do the batch querying in a mapper implementation